# DAE file not importing as expected

Tags: import, dae

I am trying to import a guitar strap from Daz to Blender. When I try to use the Daz to Blender bridge, then the object does not look good at all. Kind of mangled/distorted and not even on the same axis.

As a workaround, I exported the guitar strap from Daz as a Collada .dae file, which brings me to my situation.

It imports the file, but not as expected. There are dots drawn exactly where I would like the guitar strap to be, but yet the actual guitar strap is found on the floor -- see attached screen shot

[image: screen shot after imported file]

The following screen shot is that of the guitar strap within Daz

[image: screenshot number 2]

As you can see, the dots within Blender show perfectly how I would like the guitar strap to fit, but the object is lying flat on the ground of the scene. I am assuming that Blender knows this is the "path" for the file. How can I connect the dots/path to the file?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: removing blend file because it contains an object that was not created by myself

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else faces this weird delimma that I cannot find anywhere else, exactly like my situation, then I thought I would at least post my workaround.

First, I went back into Daz and made sure that the strap fit perfectly, using the perspective view to move back and forth between one end of the strap and the other end.

[image: screenshot in Daz]

Second, I deleted everything but the guitar strap and saved it as it's own file.

[image: screenshot of lone guitar strap]

Third, I exported the file as wavefront .obj with these custom settings

[image: screenshot of custom export]

Forth, I imported wavefront .obj from within Blender, by using these parameters

[image: screenshot of import]

Fifth, it fit perfect, as if it were made for it

[image: screenshot of the resulting import]

Turned out pretty good

[image: screenshot of a portion of the render]